# Could not GET 'https://fyber.bintray.com/maven/com/fyber/fairbid-sdk/3.0.1/fairbid-sdk-3.0.1.aar'. Received status code 403 from server: Forbidden

Tags: java

Help me solve this problem

**Could not GET 'https://fyber.bintray.com/maven/com/fyber/fairbid-sdk/3.0.1/fairbid-sdk-3.0.1.aar'. Received status code 403 from server: Forbidden**

maven { url  "https://fyber.bintray.com/maven"}

Comment: 403 indicates that you are not authorized to perform a GET at that URL.  Perhaps check with the vendor to verify your privilege to access this file.

Answer (score 0):

1- upgrade `fairbid Sdk` to

```
implementation 'com.fyber:fairbid-sdk:3.17.0'
```

2- Add in `build.gradle(project)`

```
allprojects {
   repositories {
       mavenCentral()
  }
  ...
}
```

3- Add in `build.gradle(Module)`

```
android {
    ...
    compileOptions {
       sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
       targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
  ...
}
```